# Hex encoding of INTEGERs for `asn1Coding` from `libtasn1`

Tags: asn.1

I want to encode two INTEGERs into a SEQUENCE with from `asn1Coding` from `libtasn1`.
I have to pass the integer as hex values. Obviously cryptographic integers can be very large hence there must an option to pass it as hex, but the documentation is not providing any advice.

I tried to pass 0x30, \x30, "\x30\x01". nothing works so far and the input is rejected. What is the correct way to use this tool?

`x962.asn1`

```
ECDSA { }

DEFINITIONS EXPLICIT TAGS ::=

BEGIN

Signature ::= SEQUENCE {
   r  INTEGER,
   s  INTEGER
}

END
```

`asn1.test`:

```
dp ECDSA.Signature

r "\x30\x01"
s "\x40\x03"
```

Call:

```bash
asn1Coding x962.asn1 asn1.test
```

> asn1Coding x962.asn1 asn1.test  Parse: done.
>
> var=dp, value=ECDSA.Signature var=r, value="\x30\x01" libtasn1 ERROR:
> VALUE_NOT_VALID

When trying with large integers the tool is using the largest supported int (0x7fffffffffffffff), which is wrong:

> Parse: done.
>
> var=dp, value=X962.Signature var=r,
> value=175969581411011301664416044449972632849 var=s,
> value=175969581411011301664416044449972632849
>
> name:NULL  type:SEQUENCE   name:r  type:INTEGER
> value:0x7fffffffffffffff   name:s  type:INTEGER
> value:0x7fffffffffffffff
>
> Coding: SUCCESS
>
> ### ----------------- Number of bytes=22 30 14 02 08 7f ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 02 08 7f ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
>
> OutputFile=asn1.out
>
> Writing: done.

Comment: can you show the bit of code that is calling the lib?

Comment: I added the command line call.

Comment: seems normal: you pass a string while it is expecting an integer. What do you want to achieve ? (may be this tool is not what you need)

Comment: An INTEGER in ASN.1 can have arbitrary length. I do not want to use a 32 bit integer fitting into a CPU register and being an `int` datatype but a huge 256 bit integer. For these numbers the digit must be passed in as hex.

Comment: the tool still expects an integer (even huge) ... not a string (x30x01 is 12289)

Comment: I'm not sure the internals of the tool, but if they support huge ints then I would need a tool to convert 0x846282348834335454554345A3E43D11 to an int.

Comment: 175969581411011301664416044449972632849 ... https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html ... Not very handy. Why do you use this tool in the first place ?

Comment: I have added an output when using large numbers. The number is cut to the largest possible int. So, the answer might be that the tool is not supporting what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems to solve:

1. X9.62 uses INTEGER (while x509 uses BIT STRING) and it's not convenient
2. Using INTEGER for this purpose forces the tool to support huge integers ... and it's not convenient

If your (only) need is to get the bytes for the signature, you should not bother with a tool.

Encoding a SEQUENCE of 2 INTEGER is pretty straight forward

- 0x30 (Tag for SEQUENCE)
- Length of what comes after
- 0x02 (Tag for INTEGER)
- Length (number of bytes) of r
- bytes of r (the same you wanted to put in asn1.test)
- 0x02 (Tag for INTEGER)
- Length (number of bytes) of s
- bytes of s (the same you wanted to put in asn1.test)

EDIT:
I just realized that [my tool](https://github.com/yafred/asn1-tool) does it ...

[image]

Comment: I have used this approach already, what also has to be considered is that if the integer's highest octet has in the highest bit a 1 '00' must be prefixed to the integer.

Comment: You're absolutely right:  the bits of the first octet and bit 8 of the second octet shall not all be ones; and shall not all be zero. With Java, java.math.BigInteger.toByteArray() works fine